# setInterval does not work in Chrome (work first time only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Here is my code:

```
var $cur = 0;
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $tot = document.getElementsByTagName("img").length;
    changetile();
});

function changetile() {
    if ($cur == $tot) {
        $next = 1;
    } else {
        $next = $cur + 1;
    }
    $("#tile-" + $cur).fadeOut(1000);
    $("#tile-" + $next).fadeIn(1000);
    $cur = $next;
}
var myVar = setInterval(function () {
    changetile()
}, 4500);
```

This code does not work in Chrome (it works the first time). What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Move everything into document ready.

Comment: And then save some space with `var myVar = setInterval(changetile,4000)`

Answer (score 1):

`$tot` has local scope can not be accessible outside the block.

DOM ready(`$(document).ready(function(){`) has a anonymous function so your`$tot` variable has local scope

Move all your code inside DOM Ready

```
var $cur = 0;
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $tot = document.getElementsByTagName("img").length;
    function changetile() {
        if ($cur == $tot) {
            $next = 1;
        } else {
            $next = $cur + 1;
        }
        $("#tile-" + $cur).fadeOut(1000);
        $("#tile-" + $next).fadeIn(1000);
        $cur = $next;
    }
    var myVar = setInterval(function () {
        changetile()
    }, 4500);
    changetile();
});
```

Read [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Comment: I have a doubt about `$tot` as a *local* var, could you check `function f(){v=1;};f();v;`? Chrome says `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $cur = 0;
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    var myVar = setInterval(function () {
       $tot = document.getElementsByTagName("img").length;
       changetile()
}, 4500);
});

function changetile() {
    if ($cur == $tot) {
        $next = 1;
    } else {
        $next = $cur + 1;
    }
    $("#tile-" + $cur).fadeOut(1000);
    $("#tile-" + $next).fadeIn(1000);
    $cur = $next;
}
```

Change your code like this. It will work

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is Works in my Browser( Chrome ) :

But for you its not , then you should try With this :

```
var $cur = 0,$tot;
$(document).ready(function (e) {
$tot = document.getElementsByTagName("img").length;
var myVar = setInterval(changetile,4500);
});
function changetile() {
if ($cur == $tot) {
    $next = 1;
} else {
    $next = $cur + 1;
}
$("#tile-" + $cur).fadeOut(1000);
$("#tile-" + $next).fadeIn(1000);
$cur = $next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't an issue with Chrome - it's an issue with your code.  Here is the output I got:

**First Iteration**

> Cur != tot!  VM325:14
>
> Cur = 0 $tot = 9 VM325:16
>
> Next val is : 1 VM325:17

**Second Iteration:**

> Cur != tot!  VM325:14
>
> Cur = 1 $tot = 9 VM325:16
>
> Next val is : 2 VM325:17

**Thrid:**

> Cur != tot!  VM325:14
>
> Cur = 2 $tot = 9 VM325:16
>
> Next val is : 3 VM325:17

etc.

I got this by simply putting some console.log statements in there to see what's going on:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $tot = document.getElementsByTagName("img").length;
    changetile();
});

function changetile() {
    if ($cur == $tot) {
        $next = 1;
    console.log(" Cur == tot! ");
    } else {
        $next = $cur + 1;
    console.log(" Cur != tot! ");
    }
    console.log( "Cur = " + $cur + " $tot = " + $tot );
    console.log( " Next val is : " + $next )

    $cur = $next;
}
var myVar = setInterval(changetile, 4500);
```

Edit: @tushar-gupta gives ya the answer =]  I just point you in the direction ( in case you just needed a pointer )